# How to get the column header of a particular column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data

`admit_data = np.genfromtxt('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/admission_predict.csv', delimiter=',')`

What I need is to get some particular column header. I am using the following code to get the data. But not able to get those column name

`print(admit_data[1:].tolist())`

Is there any function like `.tolist()` so that I can extract only that column's name?

**Edit 1**

Added sample data format

[image]

Comment: What is the "name of a particular column" in NumPy? Perhaps you want to look into Pandas instead of NumPy?

Comment: Well, think about it: what is the `[1:]` doing in your code? Where in `admit_data` are the column names?

Comment: @norok2 What I mean is the header of the columns that i am selecting using [1:] or [1:4] etc

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am dropping certain columns and thus i want to know the column headers of the remaining columns. I am only getting the column data with .tolist() and not the column headers

Comment: could you show `admit_data`? Perhaps it gets clearer then. As far as I know, NumPy does not support "column names" in the form of labelled array. Pandas does. On the other hand, NumPy does support [*structured arrays*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @norok2 Please see my updated question

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example](/help/mcve)? I believe you may be using structured arrays, but I suspect that the `csv` headers are not read.

Comment: With that `genfromtxt` call, `admit_data` is a 2d array of floats, with `nan` values in the first row (the column headers that it couldn't convert to floats).  Print it, or at least part, to verify that.  Or just show us what the tolist print displayed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get the column names from the `csv` with [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g. by specifying `names=True`, then the names of the columns end up in the `dtype` as `data.dtype.names`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.genfromtxt(
    io.StringIO('A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'),
    dtype=None, names=True, delimiter=',', encoding='utf8')
print(data)
# [(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6)]
print(data.dtype.names)
# ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

However, please note that with `data[1:]` you are not selecting columns, but rows! To select the rows, you have to use one of the `names`:

```
print(data[1:])
# [(4, 5, 6)]

print(data['A'])
# [1 4]

print(data[['A', 'B']])                                                                                                                      
# [(1, 2) (4, 5)]
```

and more advanced indexing are actually a bit cumbersome:

```
# print(data.shape)
# (2,)
print(data[1:][0][1])
# 5
```

---

On the other hand, [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) would offer a much more direct syntax and that is one of the main reasons for it to be the preferred tools for this use case:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'))


print(df['A'])
# 0    1
# 1    4
# Name: A, dtype: int64

print(df['A'][0])                                                                                                                              
# 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give more information about the data that you want to extract.

Based on your question, tolist() function is present for Pandas series. Better convert the admit_data as pandas series(using pd.Series() function). Then you can extract the first row as list.

Comment: I am trying to drop one feature at a time and use the data to train a model. But I want to see which are the column I am dropping. The data are just numbers with some strings as column names

Comment: Note sure about the no of columns you have , if the column count is more then there are feature selection techniques like Exhaustive Feature Selector, Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE in sklearn). In RFE, you can drop the non significant variables by providing the step values. Eg : Step 1 , will drop 1 variable and the remaining columns will be saved as list. So this might suit your case. RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=None, step=1, verbose=0). If you have 10 columns and you want only 5 columns to build model, you can give n_features as 5.